# Is there any jQuery plugin which can give a similar result as of www.squarespace.com menu?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, nav, squarespace

I need the menu to appear only after scrolling down a few hundred pixels and should be fixed at top, it's actually same as of http://www.squarespace.com/tour/overview/. So, please let me know if there's any jQuery plugin that does this or another techniques to achieve the same.

Comment: There is only horizontal right side side bar in there? I didn't saw any thing we can scroll down in it.. ???

Comment: I am sorry about the wrong link..here's the correct one http://www.squarespace.com/tour/overview/ ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same by using this plugin http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I actually posted a wrong link, here's the one that I need help with http://www.squarespace.com/tour/overview/ :)

Comment: As I know there is no any plugin available in Jquery to do that. But with jquery you can do that kind of a stuff easily. (In squarespace, seems like they have used yui )